# Spring Boot - JSP not displaying list?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I am using Spring Boot and trying to map a few of my MySQL rows into a table. For some reason, the table is not displaying any elements. I've printed the list and the list contains all of the elements, however they are not appearing in my table! I am using ModelAndView and passing my list into the model as a model object, and using an attribute name which is called in my jsp page.

Drinker entity class:

```
public class Drinker {
    private String drinker_name;
    private int drinker_phone;
    private int cc_number;
    private java.sql.Date cc_expiration;

    public Drinker(){

    }
    public Drinker(String drinker_name, int drinker_phone, int cc_number, java.sql.Date cc_expiration){
        this.drinker_name = drinker_name;
        this.drinker_phone = drinker_phone;
        this.cc_number = cc_number;
        this.cc_expiration = cc_expiration;
    }

    public String getDrinkerName(){
        return this.drinker_name;
    }
    public int getDrinkerPhone(){
        return this.drinker_phone;
    }
    public int getDrinkerCCNumber(){
        return this.cc_number;
    }
    public Date getDrinkerCCExpiration(){
        return this.cc_expiration;
    }

    public void setDrinkerName(String drinker_name){
        this.drinker_name = drinker_name;
    }
    public void setDrinkerPhone(int drinker_phone){
        this.drinker_phone = drinker_phone;
    }

    public void setDrinkerCCNumber(int cc_number){
        this.cc_number = cc_number;
    }
    public void setDrinkerCCExpiration(java.sql.Date cc_expiration){
        this.cc_expiration = cc_expiration;
    }
}
```

home.jsp

```
   <body>
        <div align="center">
            <div class="topnav">
              <a class="active" href="pino">Drinker</a>
              <a href="bars">Bars</a>
              <a href="beers">Beers</a>
              <a href="modification">Modification</a>
            </div>
            <h1>Drinker List</h1>
            <h3><a href="/newDrinker">New Drinker</a></h3>
            <table border="1">
                <th>Drinker Name</th>
                <th>Drinker Phone #</th>
                <th>Credit Card Number</th>
                <th>CC Expiration Date</th>
                <th>Action</th>

                <c:forEach var="drinker" items="${listDrinker2}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${drinker.drinker_name}</td>
                    <td>${drinker.drinker_phone}</td>
                    <td>${drinker.cc_number}</td>
                    <td>${drinker.cc_expiration}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/editContact?id=${drinker.id}">Edit</a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="/deleteContact?id=${drinker.id}">Delete</a>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
```

UserController.java:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/pino", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listDrinker(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
        List<Drinker> listDrinker = drinkerDAO.list();
        Drinker drinker = new Drinker("John", 201, 123, new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()) );
        List<Drinker> listDrinker2 = new ArrayList();
        listDrinker2.add(drinker);
        model.addObject("listDrinker2", listDrinker2);
        model.setViewName("home");
        return model;
    }
```

EDIT: I am aware that I am not passing listDrinker, which is the list that contains the entities from my database, but neither listDrinker and listDrinker2 displays **any** elements in the table.

Answer (score 1):

> I've printed the list and the list contains all of the elements,
>   however they are not appearing in my table!

Thats' because you are not adding the correct list to your model. You are fetching the entries from your **DAO** in `listDrinker` and then adding `listDrinker2` in your model.

```
List<Drinker> listDrinker = drinkerDAO.list();
Drinker drinker = new Drinker("John", 201, 123, new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()) );
List<Drinker> listDrinker2 = new ArrayList();
listDrinker2.add(drinker);
/* LOOK HERE! */
model.addObject("listDrinker2", listDrinker2);
```

Either add all the elements of `listDrinker` to `listDrinker2` using `addAll()` or change `addObject()` to,

```
model.addObject("listDrinker2", listDrinker);
```

Comment: adding the listDrinker to the model wouldn't print, so I manually made the list "listDrinker2" and tried to see if I could print the entry I manually added, but no entries appear in the table for both lists. Any idea why listDrinker2 won't even print?